# How to get multiple depots in the Optaplanner cvrptw example?

Tags: optaplanner

Currently there is just a single depot. I want to use my own data as input and I need to generate 2 depot locations with their own vehicles located to them.

Comment: Will you post your code here? what you have done till now? Try to explain your question in more detail refer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

The solution for creating is second depot is pretty easy. Depending on which file you want to change it becomes a little more tedious.

1. VRP Solution

Go to the corresponding .vrp file and scroll down to:

```
DEPOT_SECTION
1   
-1
```

Change into:

```
DEPOT_SECTION
1
2
-1
```

Here the 1 refers to the first position in the NODE_COORD_SECTION, and the 2 to the second.

2. XML Solution

Go to the corresponding XML file and go to:

```
<depotList>
<VrpDepot id="197">
  <id>1</id>
  <location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="3"/>
</VrpDepot>

'copy to get more depots  

</depotList>
```

You can then change which trucks are sourced from which warehouse (or depot).